Testing SwiftData models in test target, "failed to find a currently active container"
I'm building out a SwiftData model in the preliminary stages of app development. I'm using test-driven development (tdd) to iterate on the model and iron out kinks prior to integrating the model into the app itself.
Working with the classes works fine until I add the @Model declaration. But once the classes have been added to SwiftData, I'm unable to test them without an "active container".
import SwiftData

@Model
class StringModel {
    let string: String
    
    init(_ string: String) {
        self.string = string
    }
}

class Tester: XCTestCase {
    func testSwiftData() throws {
        let model = StringModel("foo")
        XCTAssertEqual(model.string, "foo")
    }
}

The test case crashes with the error:

Thread 1: Fatal error: failed to find a currently active container for StringModel
@Transient  
private var _$backingData: any SwiftData.BackingData<StringModel> = StringModel.createBackingData()


What's the easiest and simplest way to get a SwiftData stack set up within tests, just to test objects? I do not care about actually persisting the data or running queries, as SwiftData / Core Data provides in the real app. I just want to construct and test each class independently.

In its easiest form you need a ModelContainer instance that is active for the tests.
You can add a property to the test class
var container: ModelContainer!

And then set it up in one of the setUp methods
container = try ModelContainer(for: StringModel.self, 
                               configurations: [ModelConfiguration(isStoredInMemoryOnly: true)])


So this is what I came up with to unit test SwiftData @Model objects. You must prepare the model context to be fake, and avoid using the ModelContainer's main context.
For clarity, I use the term entity to refer to a SwiftData model object.
This is the ModelContainer extension where you will be able to use the real entities only. Do not use this in tests.
extension ModelContainer {

  /// A shared instance of ``ModelContainer`` that is used to manage the app's SwiftData entities.
  /// - Warning: Must be initialized within a `.modelContainer(_:)` in the application first call, which is in `WindowGroup`.
  static var shared: ModelContainer = {
    do {
      // Add all your entities at once here.
      return try ModelContainer(for: FooEntity.self)
    } catch {
      fatalError("Failed to create `ModelContainer` for the entities: \(error)")
    }
  }()
}


Implement and use the ModelContainer here only to avoid calling the real one in tests. You also must not call your MyAwesomeApp when running tests.

struct MyAwesomeApp: App {

  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentView()
        .modelContainer(ModelContainer.shared)
    }
  }
}


Let's prepare our SwiftData object called FooEntity.

@Model final class FooEntity {

  @Attribute(.unique) var fooID: UUID
  var name: String

  init(fooID: UUID, name: String) {
    self.fooID = fooID
    self.name = name
  }
}


Below, we provide a method to access the context for the FooEntity model. This method uses internalFakeContext in tests. The production code will use the ModelContainer.shared.mainContext.

extension FooEntity {

  // To be initialized in tests setup and clear in tear downs.
  static var internalFakeContext: ModelContext?

  @MainActor static var modelContext: ModelContext {
    guard internalFakeContext == nil else { return internalFakeContext! }
    return ModelContainer.shared.mainContext // Prod `mainContext` if not in unit tests.
  }
}


I also create a fake object to easily create FooEntity when needed.

extension FooEntity {

  static func fake(
    fooID: UUID = UUID(uuidString: "fake_uuid_string")!,
    name: String = "Fake Name"
  ) -> FooEntity {
    .init(
      fooID: fooID,
      name: name
    )
  }
}


And now, this is the fake context for your unit tests:

extension FooEntity {

  @MainActor static func fakeContext(
    insertEntities: (ModelContext) -> Void = { _ in }
  ) -> ModelContext {
    do {
      let fakeContext = try ModelContainer(
        for: FooEntity.self,
        configurations: .init(isStoredInMemoryOnly: true)
      ).mainContext
      FooEntity.internalFakeContext = fakeContext

      insertEntities(fakeContext)
      return fakeContext
    } catch {
      fatalError("Failed to create `ModelContext` for `FooEntity`: \(error)")
    }
  }
}

Sets up a fake ModelContext for unit testing.
This method creates an in-memory ModelContext and assigns it to modelContextFake. It allows for an optional closure to insert entities into the context, which is useful for preparing test scenarios with pre-existing data.
Example Usage:
// Setup the fake context with entities for tests
let fakeContext = FooEntity.fakeContext { context in
  context.insert(FooEntity.fake())
}


Be aware that in all your tests files where an entity is used, you must create the fake container within the set up and clear it within tear downs. I recommend creating methods accessible to all your tests class.

@MainActor func setUpEntities() {
  FooEntity.internalFakeContext = FooEntity.fakeContext()
}

func tearDownEntities() {
  FooEntity.internalFakeContext = nil
}

final class HomeViewModelTests: XCTestCase {

  var sut: HomeViewModel!


  override func setUp() async throws {
    try await super.setUp()
    await setUpEntities() // Set up your entities
    sut = HomeViewModel()
  }

  override func tearDown() async throws {
    sut = .none
    tearDownEntities() // Tear down your entities
    try await super.tearDown()
  }
}


And now, in your unit tests, just call the entity modelContext like you would in the production code, it will access the configurations: .init(isStoredInMemoryOnly: true) to not persist the data in the device.

@MainActor func testInsertingFooEntity() {
  let fooEntityFake = FooEntity.fake()
  let fetchRequest = FetchDescriptor<FooEntity>(
    predicate: #Predicate { $0.fooID == fooEntityFake.id }
  )

  FooEntity.modelContext.insert(fooEntityFake) // Technically here your prod code doing the real `insert`.
  let result = try FooEntity.modelContext.fetch(fetchRequest).map { $0.fooID }.isEmpty

  XCTAssertFalse(result, "`FooEntity` is indeed within the in memory container for tests.")
}

Warning When deleting all instances of a model in production code:

Don't: try? ModelContainer.shared.mainContext.delete(model: FooEntity.self)
Do: try? FooEntity.modelContext.delete(model: FooEntity.self)


First of all, love the design. Thank you.
XCode 16 doesn't like that ModelContext is not Sendable. Apparently Swift 6 requires that and can't figure out the thread dispatch.
I'm fiddling with sprinkling async and awaits here and there, but am a Swift newb, so... Help would be appreciated.

Apparently if I home my test func to @MainActor, it "fails successfully"... Fumbling through Xcode scheme configurations to see if I can get to green... Currently, something about testenv/simulator filesystem permissions...

false GREEN, now RED.
Secret sauce so far...
%>  xcodebuild -scheme [SwiftDataTests] test -testPlan [SwiftDataTests] -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 16"

just created new ones and lived with the warning logs. waiting for Cupertino to address it.

The addition of the config and container lines below solves the crash and causes the tests to pass.
func testSwiftData() throws {
    let config = ModelConfiguration(isStoredInMemoryOnly: true)
    let container = try! ModelContainer(for: StringModel.self, configurations: config)
    
    let model = StringModel("foo")
    XCTAssertEqual(model.string, "foo") // ok
}

Using a configuration with isStoredInMemoryOnly seems well-suited for these kinds of tests.
